# cancel btn for a contenteditable html option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm really new to the contenteditable variable for html and so I want to dig your brains a bit :).

I want to allow users to edit content if they wish to but I'm stuck in the cancel btn option.

How can I retain the previous content if a user clicks the cancel btn? I've been looking at the documentation but struggle to find something. Please see the code below:

````
const cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancel-btn');

console.log(editBtn);

function editable() {
    const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
    const h4 = document.querySelector('h4');
    const p = document.querySelector('p');

    h3.className = 'edit';
    h4.className = 'edit';
    p.className = 'edit';
    h3.contentEditable = true;
    h4.contentEditable = true;
    p.contentEditable = true;

    addSaveBtn();
}

function cancelEdit() {
    const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
    const h4 = document.querySelector('h4');
    const p = document.querySelector('p');

    h3.classList.remove('edit');
    h4.classList.remove('edit');
    p.classList.remove('edit');
    h3.contentEditable = false;
    h4.contentEditable = false;
    p.contentEditable = false;
    removeSaveBtn();
}

function addSaveBtn() {
    const cardAccess = document.querySelector('.card');
    const saveBtn = document.createElement('button');
    saveBtn.id = 'edit-save-btn';
    saveBtn.textContent = 'Save';
    if (document.getElementById('edit-save-btn')) {
        return;
    } else {
        cardAccess.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', saveBtn);
    }

    saveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
        const h4 = document.querySelector('h4');
        const p = document.querySelector('p');
        h3.classList.remove('edit');
        h4.classList.remove('edit');
        p.classList.remove('edit');
        h3.contentEditable = false;
        h4.contentEditable = false;
        p.contentEditable = false;
        removeSaveBtn();
    });
}

function removeSaveBtn() {
    if (!document.getElementById('edit-save-btn')) {
        return;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('edit-save-btn').remove();
    }
}

editBtn.addEventListener('click', editable);
cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', cancelEdit);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

To add a cancel button:

1. Create a variable that stores the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) when save was pressed.
2. Set the `innerHTML` of the `contenteditable` element to this variable when the cancel button is pressed.

Full Example:

```js
// Set up the variable
var savedText = content.innerHTML;

save.onclick = ()=>{
  // store the current content in savedText
  savedText = content.innerHTML;
}
cancel.onclick = ()=>{
  // set the new html content to what was stored
  content.innerHTML = savedText;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable="true"><h1>Edit Me!</h1></div>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

---

The `contentEditable` property takes a string, so you probably want something like this:

```js
function cancelEdit() {
    const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
    const h4 = document.querySelector('h4');
    const p = document.querySelector('p');

    h3.classList.remove('edit');
    h4.classList.remove('edit');
    p.classList.remove('edit');
    h3.contentEditable = "false";
    h4.contentEditable = "false";
    p.contentEditable = "false";
    removeSaveBtn();
}
function editable() {
    const h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
    const h4 = document.querySelector('h4');
    const p = document.querySelector('p');

    h3.className = 'edit';
    h4.className = 'edit';
    p.className = 'edit';
    h3.contentEditable = "true";
    h4.contentEditable = "true";
    p.contentEditable = "true";

    addSaveBtn();
}
```

Example with toggling:

```js
toggle.onclick = ()=>{
  content.contentEditable = (!content.isContentEditable).toString();
  toggle.textContent = content.isContentEditable ? "Turn Editability Off" : "Turn editability On"
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable="true"><h1>Edit Me!</h1></div>

<button id="toggle">Turn Editability Off</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! yes, this could shorten my code when it comes toggling contenteditable. What I don't know is to go back to the previous initial text if I decide not to edit after inputting something in the text box. Do you have any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @CarlosEscobar Do you want it to persist? (i.e. using `localStorage`)

Comment: Hi, I just need it to go back to previous text if the user decides to cancel the edit

Comment: @CarlosEscobar see my updated answer which explains this

Comment: Hi Nate! thank you so much.. I was actually trying with textContent instead of innerHTML! :)! really appreciate your help

Comment: @CarlosEscobar Make sure to upvote and [mark the answer as a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so future googlers know the answer!

Comment: How do I do this? :( I'm very new to coding :(

Comment: @CarlosEscobar No worries! If you go to the top of my answer on the left you should be able to see an up arrow, then a number, then a down arrow. Below the down arrow should be a gray checkmark. When you click on the gray checkmark it will show this answer more prominently, and lets other people know the question has an answer.